# How can I avoid duplicate digit in the cicle result

Tags: python-3.x

The result of the code includes separetly "min" and "max" values. Can't get how I can print only result of cicle?
For examle, whan I set min = 1, max = 3 the result is:
**1
3
1
2
3**

And I need **1 2 3** without first **1 3**.

```
min = int(input())
max = int(input())
while min <= max:
    print(min)
    min = min + 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing seeing the the 1 and 3 as you're inputting them? What happens if you put a `print('output begins below this line')` before the while?

Comment: (and you are aware Python has a builtin for this? `for value in range(min, max): print(value)`?)

Comment: There are results:

`min = int(input())
max = int(input())
print('output begins below this line') 
while min <= max:
    print(min)
    min = min + 1`

1
3
output begins below this line
1
2
3

Comment: So that's fine then - the output is as expected (appearing below the "output begins below" line). The 1 and 3 you're seeing is the echo of the input you're providing... You can make that even clearer by changing it to `min = int(input('Enter the min: '))` to see that... (and also give a clue as to what exactly the user is meant to enter...)

Comment: Oh! It's become so obvious now! Why I don't get it from the start? Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: As another aside - don't forget that python has a buitin `range` for what you're doing... and it's best to avoid naming things after builtin functions (of which `min` and `max` are in Python) - maybe use `start` and `end` instead...)

Comment: Yeah. I have allready try it - really good. Thank you for you advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely on the ide or python environment you are using. May I know which environment you are using?
Because when I ran here https://ideone.com/lUmjKL everything seems fine.

```
min = int(input())
max = int(input())
while min <= max:
    print(min)
    min = min + 1
```

Let me know.

Comment: The problem is solved. The reason is that I took the inputs as part of the outputs. But now its OK. Thank you for you attention fo my problem an for link - it more convenient for debugging than the tool I have.